# Complete Maximum Number of Tasks

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have 3 resources ( A,B and C). Now there are some tasks to be performed where each task require X amount of resource A, Y amount of resource B and Z amount of resource C. At the beginning I had BA amount of A , BB amount of B, BC amount of C and buying each new A resource cost PA similarly buying new B resource cost PB and buying new resource C costs PC.

Now question is **if I have P total amount then how many maximum tasks can be completed.**

### Example:

Let suppose each task requires 3 unit of resource A (=X) , 2 unit of resource B (=Y) and 1 unit of resource C (=Z) .At the beginning lets suppose we have 6 units of resource A(=BA) , 4 units of resource B(=BB) and 1 units of resource C(=BC) .Each resource A costs 1(=PA) , each resource B costs 2(=PB) and each resource C costs 3(=PC).

Now lets suppose we have total of 4 dollar(=P).

Then maximum tasks that can be done is 2 here.

Explanation : Each task needs 3 units of A , 2 units of B and 1 unit of C . At beginning we have already has 6 units of A , 4 units of B and 1 unit of C. This can be used for only 1 task due to lack of resource C. Then we can buy 1 more unit of resource C for cost of 3 dollars so as to complete 1 more task, giving a total of 2 tasks.

Perhaps their can be direct relation to solve it. I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember years ago, in school, learning about derivatives to optimize area.. if you think about it in terms of 2 variables, you can figure out this problem as a area vs perimeter optimization.. ex: if I have a 128ft rope to define the perimeter of a rectangle what is the length of sides that gives-me the bigest area..

Any rectangle must have a 
length L and a width W.  For the perimeter to be 128, `2L + 2W = 128`, 
or `L + W = 64`.
The area of this rectangle is L*W.  We want to pick 
the L and W such that we get the maximum area L*W.

So if I variate L, `W = 64 - L`;

so the equation will be `y = x * (64 - x)`

if you plot it out [in google](https://www.google.pt/search?q=y%20=%20x%20%2a%20%2864%20-%20x%29), you will see the optimal area is the peek of the funcition

so the optimal area is 1024 when the side X is 32 which means the other side will be `Y = 64 - X`, or also 32 in this case a perfect square..

of course to apply this to your problem you have 3 variables.. but i guess you can translate this to a problem to volume optimization given the surface and plot it out in 3D.. I could not do it because I'm not a math wizard.. but I guess if you go on a math forum.. I'm sure someone will help..